# Testing BelongsToMany relationship with pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to figure out how to create all the data based on this relationship testing in Laravel.

**Company Model**

```php
class Company
{
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Store::class, 'company_id');
    }

    public function employers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'employers', 
            'company_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Store Model**

```php
class Store
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }

    public function employers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'employers', 
            'store_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```php
class User
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'employers', 
            'user_id', 'company_id');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'employers', 
            'user_id', 'store_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$company = Company::factory()->hasStores(
    Store::factory()->hasEmployers(User::factory())
)->create();
dd($company) // App\Models\Company {#2470... Ok!

$store = $company->store()->first();
dd($store) // App\Models\Store {#2479... Ok!

$user = $store->employers()->first();
dd($user) // null (T-T)
```

Background: this is an application that allows a proprietor to own several companies. For that reason, I got many relationships, and even so, employees sometimes can only belong to a single company or store.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $store = $company->store->first();
  dump($store);
  
  $user = $store->employers->first();
  dump($user);
```

Comment: thanks, but I tried, but "employers" is a many-to-many relationship, I need to call "model" `$store->employers()`  if I just call `$store->employers` becomes a `Eloquent\Collection`, i guess i'm missing something... by the way, still be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with DB Facade

```
private $employ;
    
public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->employ = Employ::factory()->create([
            'id' => 14,
            'name' => 'Name Employ'
        ]);
    }  



public function test_pivote_table()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'name' => 'User test'
         );
        

        //here :)

        DB::table('name_pivote_table')->insert([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'employ_id' => $this->employ->id
        ]);
}
```

Credits to Fguzman :)